# Is an language with interpreter like PHP faster with smaller code?

Tags: php, performance

as my webprojects are getting bigger I wonder if PHP interprets this code,

```
<?php
    function helloWorldOutput($helloworldVariable) {
        echo 'Hello World' . $helloworldVariable;
    }

    helloWorldOutput("I am PHP");
?>
```

slower than this:

```
<?php 
    function a($b) { echo 'Hello World'+$b; }
    a("I am PHP");
?>
```

Because PHP is an interpreted language without compiled binary I think the second sample should be a bit faster. Is that true, and is there any kind of pre-interpreting mechanic which caches a faster version of the code in PHP?

Comment: It has to parse slightly more, so yes, it will be slower. But the performance difference will be negligible.

Comment: That might be right, but I want to know if there is any difference, or if PHP has a mechanism to prevent this.

Comment: What do you mean, a difference? Performance difference: It will take negligibly longer to parse. Functional difference: no. Internally PHP might hash strings to make lookups approximately the same time, but you still end up with more characters to hash. It's likely after the parsing stage it's identical.

Comment: But does PHP parse it everytime or is there a cache for already interpreted scripts?

Comment: Reading [this](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.wincache.php) suggests PHP doesn't cache parsed scripts by default. Otherwise the "PHP Opcode Cache" would seem redundant.

Comment: Judging from your code, how easily you are mistaking sum operator (`+`) with concatenation (`.`), you should really stop worrying about such micro-optimization.

Comment: Well, I am sorry. That was a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will take some extra time to parse/compile the larger code to byte code. The time is usually negligible, so you should probably just not worry about it since there are better ways to deal with the time spent compiling.

What you would do for quite a bit more performance boost, is to use a [PHP accelerator like for example APC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators#Alternative_PHP_Cache_.28APC.29) that will cache compiled code and eliminate the whole compile step except for at the first access to a page.

Using an accelerator will remove any possible downside with keeping your code commented and clear, and lets you concentrate on functionality instead of shortening your code.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing the first version and the calls to it will take longer. So if you decide on using the first version and call a function with a name that lone many, **many** times just because of the parsing the second version will be slightly faster. As of the actual function execution - no both functions will be equally faster.

Still my advice is do not ever attempt to do such micro-optimizations. Performance will improve just slightly, readability will suffer **greatly**.

Comment: Also, using an opcode cache like apc makes it even more pointless.

Comment: Of course readability will suffer, but I just wanted to know this. APC is an good point, that answers the part of the question, if there is an cache for code.

Answer (score 0):

the first example has fewer characters which means it's farset to parse, 
php runs some sort of bytecode internally so execution speed will not differ much.

the slowest bit is probably reading the file from disk, and short code will win that race easily.